# Cursorfetch error of number of variables in my fetch into statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Unsure what is wrong with my code here. Been looking over this the past 3 hours and everything seems correct but I am getting this cursorfetch error when trying to execute the procedure.
`Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.`

In the text editor, it also underlines all of my `Sum_Salary` variables with red in the case statements.

Again, all of this seems correct to me and I cannot find out what is the problem in my code.

```
create procedure SP_Report_NEW_Budget
as 
begin
if exists (select * from VDept_Budget)
    create table NEW_Dept_Budget 
    (
        Dept_No         int,
        Dept_Name       varchar(30),
        COUNT_Emp       int,
        New_SUM_Salary  int,
        New_AVE_Salary  int
    )

    declare @depNumber  int,
            @depName    varchar(30),
            @empCount   int,
            @sumSalary  int,
            @aveSalary  int;
    declare tableCursor cursor for
    select Dept_Name, Dept_Number, No_Emp, Sum_Salary, Ave_Salary, 
        case
            when Dept_Number = 1 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.1))
            when Dept_Number = 4 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.2))
            when Dept_Number = 5 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.3))
            when Dept_Number = 7 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.4))
        end as New_SumSalary,
        case
            when Dept_Number = 1 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.1)) / No_Emp
            when Dept_Number = 4 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.2)) / No_Emp
            when Dept_Number = 5 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.3)) / No_Emp
            when Dept_Number = 7 then (Sum_Salary + (Sum_Salary * 0.4)) / No_Emp
        end as New_AveSalary

        from VDept_Budget

    open tableCursor

    begin
        fetch next from tableCursor into @depNumber, @depName, @empCount, @sumSalary, @aveSalary

    begin 
        insert into NEW_Dept_Budget values(@depNumber, @depName, @empCount, @sumSalary, @aveSalary)
        fetch next from tableCursor into @depNumber, @depName, @empCount, @sumSalary, @aveSalary

    end
    end
    close tableCursor

    select*from NEW_Dept_Budget

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know your data too well, I'm guessing that the issue is potentially an unhandled case in your case statements. It looks like your departments are numeric and skip 2, 3 and 6. If you have anything with any of those departments, your case statement doesn't look like it will be able to handle it thus causing an issue in your insert statement.

Also, for simplicities sake, you may be able to make your code a bit easier to read if you update the case statements to (purely a suggestion):

`when Dept_Number = 1 then (Sum_Salary * 1.1) / No_Emp
 when Dept_Number = 4 then (Sum_Salary * 1.2) / No_Emp`